# Python Exercise +=

Tags: python

```
k = 0
for z in xrange(x,y,2):  
    k += 1
print (k == 3)
```

so I'm trying to find values for x & y that fulfill this.  I'm getting x = 1 and y =2 because 1+2=3=k.  But the += part is throwing me up.  anyone able to solve this?

Comment: It's adding one to k each time through.

Comment: k += 1 means add 1 to the value of k.

Comment: sorry about that, basically what values of x and y work?

Comment: what are you expecting as the output true?

Comment: Sure, he could have looked stuff up... but this is a reasonably acceptable question for someone who doesn't know how that code works. He's a newbie, the answers here help, no reason to downvote to oblivion.

Comment: @pcalcao the downvotes are because OP did not pose a question.  Instead OP just dropped some code

Comment: so x=0 y=1 as each is incremented by one

Comment: afaik += and -= and *= and /= are valid operators in most languages

Answer (score 2):

So the question is asking you, what are the first and second values needed in that `xrange` call so that k, having been incremented by one each time through, will end up with the value 3.

You should look up `xrange` in the documentation, paying attention to what each of the parameters does (not forgetting the third parameter which is set to 2 here).

Comment: explaining: xrange(a,b,c); a is the start, b is the end, c is the step. for example, xrange(0,10,1) means start at 0, then count by 1 until you reach 10, then stop.

Comment: @Inbar I purposely didn't explain that, since it's clear that part of the homework is to get the OP to understand how to find things out for himself.

Comment: that may be the case, but i let the OP make his own decisions, if he has come here for help, i will help him.

Comment: gracias amigos! so x = .5 and y = 2.5

Comment: @GeorgePutin: nothing in your question indicates that `x + y` should equal 3.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see what `+=` actually does, try the following:

```
a = 0
a+=1  # (0+1)
print (a) # 1 
a += 3 # (1+3)
print (a) # 4
```

Hopefully you can use that knowlege in conjuction with the documentation for the [range](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) function to figure out your problem (for this problem, you can view `xrange` and `range` as equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

So what you're actually trying to do is construct an `xrange` object that will return exactly 3 numbers.

The first two arguments to `xrange` are the start value (which can be anything at all for your example), and the end value (which is, in effect, the minimum value that will never be in the range.) Given whatever start value you choose, you need to pick an end value such that a range starting with the start value, incrementing by 2 each time, will contain 3 values.

Solution is left to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

explaining: xrange(a,b,c); a is the start, b is the end, c is the step. for example, xrange(0,10,1) means start at 0, then count by 1 until you reach 10, then stop

explaining: +=; a += b: is saying take the value a and add b to it.

x = 1 and y = 2 doesnt work for you, is because your starting at 1, and then you add 2 to it, getting 3. this is higher than y (2) so it stops. thus, the loop only happens once, so the value of k is 1.